# How to the get range of 1 to 10 by index?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

I have a collection of lessons divided by levels
Each level has 10 chapters.

```
level 1 = chapter 1 to 10
level 2 = chapter 11 to 20
level 3 = chapter 21 to 30
and so on..
```

So my question is, what is the math formula to get the level by only knowing the chapter.

> Let's say I want to know the level of chapter 12.

it should be:

```
level = function(12 ...)
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like level$=\lceil \frac {\text{chapter}}{10}\rceil$ works

Comment: does that mean ceil?

Comment: actually I just found out too ceil(chapter/10)

Comment: @bn.:  Yes, those brackets are the usual way to show the ceiling function.  Upside down they become the floor function.

Comment: Isn't it $\lceil \frac{Chapter}{10} \rceil +1$ ?

Comment: + one if you do it with floor. ceil works perfectly so far. Thank you!

Comment: $1+\left\lfloor \frac{C-1}{10}\right\rfloor$. Ceiling is better!